# Using observablecollection with buttons

Tags: c#, button, observablecollection

I have an observablecollection to create buttons the problem is that each of these buttons call the same event handler. i am trying to make it so that each button has their own unique id so that they can be distinguished from one another. the code used to create the button elements is

```
public class button
{
    public bool IsEmpty { get; set; } 
    public int ID {get; set;}

    public button(int button_Number)
    {
        IsEmpty = true;
        ID = button_Number;

    }
}
```

I is added to a observablecollection in the following code

```
        ButtonCollection = new ObservableCollection<cChipVM>();

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < iNumChips ; ++i )
        {
            ButtonCollection.Add( new button(i) );

        }
```

the xml for the button is the following

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate">
        <Button x:Name="Button" Uid="{Binding Path=ID}" Click="Button_Click" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="7" Width="25" Height="25" ClickMode="Press" Opacity="0.9" Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="True" AllowDrop="True" IsTabStop="False">
            <Button.Style>                    
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEmpty}" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Button.Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF5ED426" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEmpty}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Button.Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF1766F0" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>

                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
```

When it tries to set the Uid with this method the system crashes, any recommendation how to fix this or any other solution where each button can have a unique ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Button.Tag property to store ID and in the handler inspect the value of Tag

```
<Button Tag="{Binding Path=ID}" Click="Button_Click" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="7" Width="25" Height="25" ClickMode="Press" Opacity="0.9" Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="True" AllowDrop="True" IsTabStop="False">
```

UPDATE : Button click handler

```
public void Button_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{ 
      var myButton = (Button)sender;
      int id = Convert.ToInt32(myButton.Tag);
}
```

Comment: So I tried this out but it seems like Tags value is remaining NULL even after ID is set

Comment: Hard to say why. This should work. Infact your entire data object should be in Button.DataContext property. Maybe you should check inside event handler what's the value of button.DataContext

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused what you are saying, right now what I am doing is

        `private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myButton = Convert.ToInt32(this.Tag);
        }`

Comment: Well that's wrong :) you need var myButton = (Button) sender;  Your button is in "sender" argument to the event handler method. "this" is a reference to a Window or user control that declares event handler method.

Comment: @yawnobleix Therw's your Click handler in answer edit. You should implement some additional error checking, eg. Convert.ToInt32 could faile if Tag does not contain  int number.